# Use SMB2 or SMB3 in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-xp, smb, smb3

i have multiple PC's and the one is on Windows XP and the other ones are on Windows 7 & 10. I wanted to ask if there is any way to use SMB2 or 3 on the Windows XP PC? A upgrade isn't possible unfortunately, since it has programs that are only available on XP.

Is there any third party software to enable SMB 2 or 3 on XP? Or is there any other way to transfer files between a Windows XP and a Windows 7 / 10 PC?

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you want the other computers to be able to _pull_ files from the XP system, or do you want the WinXP PC to _push_ files to other computers?

Comment: The XP System should be able to push files to the other computers

Comment: Is that a requirement? Doing it from the other direction (having the Win7/10 systems initiate the copy from XP) would be much easier to set up in several ways.

Comment: I think that might also be possible, if that's easier. I can use a jump server then to manage the files.

Comment: I suppose those XP apps don't run in Win10's XP-mode nor in a WInXP VM inside WIn10?

Comment: Yes, they unfortunately don't run there. we tried often with different versions of Windows XP (With Oracle VM Box etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any third party software to enable SMB 2 or 3 on XP?

In theory it *might* be possible to run Samba (the Linux SMB server) via Cygwin and turn XP into a SMB2 server, but I suspect it will be really annoying to do so; the last version of Cygwin that ran on XP didn't have a Samba package and I'm not sure whether it even provides the necessary capabilities.

I haven't seen of any other projects that would make that possible.

> Or is there any other way to transfer files between a Windows XP and a Windows 7 / 10 PC?

SFTP is always an option – you can find several SSH servers and SSH/SFTP clients for Windows XP (and of course for later versions).

For example, you could install Bitvise WinSSHd on the Windows XP system to turn it into an SFTP server (I *think* the latest version is still XP-compatible), then have the other PCs access its files through any SFTP client you want (WinSCP; PuTTY's pscp.exe/psftp.exe; FileZilla…)

Doing it the other way around (with XP being a client that pushes files to various Win7/10 servers) is also possible – Win10 even has a built-in OpenSSH server – but is slightly more work, and in general not a good plan security-wise to have an "insecure" machine keep a collection of credentials to all of your "secure" machines.

There are also plenty of "traditional FTP" servers that can run on both WinXP and Win7/10; some of them even support FTPS for data encryption (e.g. FileZilla Server).

A third option is HTTP; there exist a few HTTP servers for Windows (including Apache httpd, as well as several "small" file servers such as HFS). This is generally download-only, although with a WebDAV-compatible server it could handle uploads.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to setup a FileZilla Client and Server right now, also will install OpenSSH / Bitvise for SFTP. Is there maybe a way to automate the transfer from FileZilla with a script instead of downloading all files manually?

Comment: I don't know about FileZilla specifically (though I'd guess no), but there are other tools more suitable for that – for example, WinSCP should work well, for both FTP and SFTP (it comes with a winscp.com that's meant for scripting); there's probably also a few Windows versions of wget too (HTTP/FTP-only).

Comment: Alright thank you, i will also have a look at WinSCP for sure!